# Contraposition with assumptions

Tags: logic, proof-writing

I was just doing a practice problem, and found myself in the following scenario, which I've abstracted to get at the logical question that I have.

We want to prove: Given an assumption $A$, $B$ and $C$ cannot both be true at once.

If we can show "$B\implies\text{not }C$", I would usually just take a contrapositive and conclude that "$C\implies\text{not }B$".

However, I've really shown "$A\text{ and } B\implies \text{not }C$", and the contrapositive of this is not what I'm after. Further, if I try to take the contrapositive of "$A\text{ and } B\implies A\text{ and not }C$" and use De Morgan's laws, I can't seem to produce anything like "$A\cap C\implies\text{not }B$".

So, now I'm considering the possibility that contraposition does not always work in the presence of an ambient assumption $A$, but I'm struggling to find an example where it fails. I was wondering if anyone can point out my error or provide an example that would crystallize this for me.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asked to show that "If $A$ is true, then $B$ and $C$ cannot both be true at once". This means to show that $A \implies \neg (B \wedge C)$. Writing out the definition of implication, this is $\neg A \vee \neg (B \wedge C)$. Which is $\neg A \vee (\neg B \vee \neg C)$.

Since disjunction/OR is associative and commutative, it doesn't matter what order you arrange them. You could also write this as $(\neg A \vee \neg B) \vee \neg C$ or as $(\neg A \vee \neg C) \vee \neg B$. These last two ways of writing are equivalent to "$A$ and $B$ $\implies$ not $C$" and "$A$ and $C$ $\implies$ not $B$", respectively.

Comment: Thanks. This is the one. The diversity of answers implies that I stated the question poorly, but this is what I was looking for: in my phrasing, one can still take contrapositives when there is an assumption in the background.

Comment: Yes, this is quite a common scenario. You usually have some underlying assumption $A$ throughout, and you want to show that $B$ implies $C$. It is natural to expect that the assumption $A$ can be kept throughout and to prove the statement $B \implies C$ however we want.

Comment: Another way to think about your question is: what you want to show is $A \implies (B \implies \neg C)$. Which is equivalent to $A \implies (C \implies \neg B)$.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove $A\to\neg(B\land C)$; the contrapositive of this is $B\land C\to\neg A$. In words, the contrapositive is ‘if $B$ and $C$ are both true, then $A$ is not true’.

Comment: Hi Brian, looks like there're some typos here. In words it should be if $B$ and $C$ are both true, then $A$ is not true.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín: You’re absolutely right; thanks! Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

$(A\land B)\to \lnot C$ is equivalent to $A\to(B\to \lnot C)$ by law of Exportation.

However, what you want to prove is that these are also equivalent to $A\to\lnot(B\land C)$.

Use the law of Implication Negation, $\lnot(P\to Q) \iff P\land\lnot Q$, and Double Negation equivalences.